# Mysql dump to SQL-92

Tags: mysql, database, dump, ansi-sql-92

I have a http://www.product-open-data.com/download/ POD Database - dump and it's MySQL dump.
What I need for Virtuoso Sponger is SQL-92 dump is there any way to convert it automaticaly to SQL-92.

It would help me a lot. I can't imagine rewriting 2,6 milion rows :D.

Thanks
Jakub